# Which hooks can alter the display of a node?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I have a custom content type in Drupal 7. It consists of a fixed number of images. I would like to make it so that when its viewed, it comes up as a form. Each image would have a text area underneath, and when a user hits 'submit', the text they entered are displayed below each image.

We're not going to store the text that they enter for the nodes. It's just going live for that form submission.

What hooks can I use to alter the display and functionality of my content type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the best solution is [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7). Unfortunately it gets called on all node renderings, so I'm putting in a check for my content type. The hook `hook_view()` also exists, but that's only for content types that are completely defined within the module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is going to work, but the first thing I would try is to create a custom field formatter for image fields. The formatter should check if form data has been posted. If so, it displays the image with the posted text (using [check_plain()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7), of course). If not, it displays the image with the form field.